# N people occupy N points in a circle, after random adjacent movement how many points are empty?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose we have n points in a circle with 1 person at each point. If every person randomly moves either left or right to one of their direct neighbors, what is the expected number of empty points in the circle after everyone moves?

I'm having some trouble figuring out exactly how to go about solving this problem. My current thought process is that the neighbors of every person have to make a certain choice for a point to be empty, but I can't put this into a formula. I feel that indicator random variables could help.

Comment: Assuming you are looking for the *expected number* of spaces which are empty, yes indicator random variables are indeed the correct way to go.  For each *space* consider the probability that it remains empty after everyone moves.  A space remains empty iff the person to the right of the space moves right instead of left and the person to the left of the space moved left instead of right.  Can you figure out then the probability that the first space remains empty?  Now that we have that, do you see what is left to do to find the expected total number of empty spaces?

Comment: @JMoravitz so basically, my understanding is that we can find the expectation that a point is empty (which should be 1/4 given the left neighbor goes left and the right neighbor goes right) and then sum over the all these expectations to find the expectation for the number of empty points. Would it essentially just be n/4 or am I oversimplifying this problem? Thank you!

Comment: That is exactly it.  It really is that simple (assuming people's choices are uniform and independent) but learning and outsourcing the theorems that it works this way can take some time